# Firebase Password reset email throws an error "auth/user-not-found" for newly created User

Tags: angular, email, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to create a system where the admin adds users and then a random password is created and the details are added to the database.

I would then immediately send an email with the reset password email template.

I get this error : `"auth/user-not-found"`

1. I am only triggering the Reset password email when the promise returns a success.
2. I have also tried triggering the email function after 3 seconds, but still I receive the same message.
3. The Username has been created successfully.

Any suggestions? Is it only when the email has been verified that this can be used?

Edit:

To initialize the App again, I used this in a service:

```
constructor(private errorCodes: ErrorCodesService, private afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.fb = {
      apiKey: "***************",
      authDomain: "********************",
      databaseURL: "https://*****.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "***********",
      storageBucket: "*********.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "***********"

    };

    this.varSecondaryAccess = firebase.initializeApp(this.fb, 'secondary');
  }
```

Earlier, I was creating the User in this service, and then was updating the Realtime database from another service. I thought maybe it is because the other service accesses the initialized app from the app.module.ts. So after reading the comments, that got me thinking.

```
createUser(email, pey, formValue) {
    this.emailId=formValue.email;
    this.varSecondaryAccess.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pey)
      .then(user => {
        this.newForm = {};
        this.newForm[user.uid] = formValue;
        console.log(this.newForm);
        this.updateTable();
      })
      .catch(error => "error");
  }

  updateTable() {
    this.afDB.object('/users/').update(this.newForm)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Table updated")
        this.ResetPassword()
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  ResetPassword() {
    alert(this.emailId);
    this.varSecondaryAccess.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.emailId)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("email sent");
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

UPDATE: Now I get the "email sent" console.log message but the email has not been delivered. I checked spam and everything.

Comment: When you createUser, can you see the user in the Firebase Console? Also make sure you are using the same project to create the user and to send the password reset.

Comment: Yes. I see the user in the consol

Comment: Yes. I see the user in the console. It has been created. It is for the same project but I am initialising another instance of the same project. The reasons is that I am creating an admin dashboard and if I were to user the createuserwithemailandpassword method without initialising another instance, the new user is authenticated. So I am initialising another context of the same project and adding the user. Both the authentication area and some properties I have added at the same time to the real time database are being added.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "initialising another instance of the same project" Code snippets of what you are doing would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry @bojeil. I have updated the question accordingly. The "email sent" console.log message is being seen, but the email is not being delivered. Checked spam and other places

Comment: Sometimes the emails are slow to deliver. Try sending the reset password from the Firebase Console to confirm the behavior is the same. (hover over the user's row and click the 3 vertical dots and reset password).

Comment: Tried that too.  I clicked on "reset" password in the firebase console for three emails (one .gmail.com id and the others a custom domain). It says "email has been sent" but no email is delivered. Have I not done something very basic, like select a feature in the firebase console? Or do you think I should look at third party email providers and look at workarounds for this? (Any suggestions would be great). It would be a bad impression with those who test out the product. (Emails were sent about 6 mins ago.). Btw I have checked the spam folder too.

Comment: UPDATE :First batch of emails sent about 30 mins ago were received. Out of that one says reset link has expired. The ones sent from the firebase console haven't been received yet. If anyone can suggest a third party solution please do. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried too. I think there is some issue right now with Sendgrid. They are usually instantaneous. Also if you send multiple password reset emails, I believe the last one will expire the older ones.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil. Your initial comment go me thinking which made me correct my errors. For the reset email part, I am looking at other ways to do this as I need fail safes.